# Updating Android Application

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if there is a way I can update my Android application which is not listed on the Android Market. I mean, maybe thorough my website? Any ideas? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can make downloadable your signed .apk file through your website via http.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jorgesys, but I didn't exactly get you there, can you elaborate a little please?

Comment: for example i have a html with links to my .apk files,
http://prueba.agenciareforma.com/webs/elnorte/android/Appsfortest.html
 the user click the link and get the file to install manually.